# Javascript Page Load Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript

I have this code on my page returning this error:

Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Basically, I'm trying to build a flipbook.
It will have multiple papers (undefined number of papers (would change per user)), each will have a different Z-Index for correct display.

This is the code:

```
 //Adding this part for it to run after page load:
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 //Defining my constant (each paper has an id of p + a number (e.g. #p1, #p2, etc):
 const totalPapers = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="p"]').length;
 //Looping to find each item z-index:
 for (let i = 1; i <= totalPapers; i++) {
      const paperSelector = `#p${i}`;
      const zIndexValue = totalPapers - i + 1;
      document.querySelector(paperSelector).style.zIndex = zIndexValue;
      }
 });
```

Anybody knows why?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code?